# Transitioning from FlexBuilder 3 to FlashBuilder 4 ... there and back again

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, ide, flexbuilder, flash-builder

It's growing pains time again. Some of our stuff requires FlashBuilder 4 and some still requires FlexBuilder 3. Both are installed OK, and no projects use both IDEs. The trouble is, when I go back to work on a FlexBuilder 3 project it takes freakin' forever to build and I get weird errors like these:

[image]

This doesn't seem to cause any identifiable problems except to throw up a modal dialog at various points in the build process, forcing user interaction. But I do notice that memory fills up fast in FB3 and generally FB3 starts behaving strangely and ultimately quits once it gets up over 700MB.

This is only a temporary bridge situation until we get all projects into FB4, but "temporary" could mean weeks if not months. Does anyone have any advice for how to get through this bridge period? Is there anything I can do to make these two IDEs work and play well together? Failing that, does anyone know what "java.lang.String" is the "reason" for the problem? Does Eclipse have a resource bundle somewhere that is getting corrupted when i go back and forth between the two?

Comment: Can you build successfully from the command line without these issues? That would help isolate whether this is a compiler or IDE issue.

Comment: @BrianLy:  When I do an ant build or a maven install, with or without unit tests, none of these errors shows up.

Comment: Are you trying to run both IDEs at once?  It may be a problem due to Java itself, where two IDEs want different versions of Java, for compatibility reasons.  If you run them separately, it may help ensure that each gets the version of Java it wants.

Failing that, are you using the standalone version of Flash/Flex Builder, or are you plugging into a version of Eclipse?  With FB3, it's a lot less painful to use the exact version of Eclipse they recommend, rather than try to plug it into a newer version.

Comment: @Warren: Thanks, but I don't run the two at the same time.

Comment: They should work fine together. But you're going to have problems if you are sharing a workspace between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you need in Flex Builder 3 that means you cannot just use the project in Flash Builder 4?

Is there a reason why you can't move your projects to Flash Builder 4, but specify that you want to continue using Flex 3 SDK? Have you tried that and run into issues?

Thanks,

Andrew
Adobe

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. As it happens, my computer died last week and I had to get a new one, so as part of my migration process I am simply going to start using FlashBuilder 4, even though it has problems with the ClearCase plugin. Cheers, and  your first checkmark.