# Using BOTH Flexbuilder 3 AND FlashBuilder on the same machine

Tags: flash, flexbuilder

I have been using the standalone Flexbuilder3 for a while now on my mac without a problem.  While I debate whether its worth the hefty upgrade to FlashBuilder (or to switch to FDT) I'd like to have both applications installed and accessible on the same machine. According to the official docs, this should be no problem. However, in reality, when I install FlashBuilder, I am no longer able to launch Flexbuilder3. It crashes, hangs on launch. And no, I am not trying to run both at the same ti me.

If I de-install FlashBuilder, no problem, FB3 runs fine....

Answer (score 1):

I too had problems. See my [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507710/transitioning-from-flexbuilder-3-to-flashbuilder-4-there-and-back-again) on this topic.

In the end, our Windows 7 machines arrived and I decided to try to do everything in FlashBuilder 4. This has its own problems, especially when using SDK 3.3 on some projects, but that's another topic.